# EFI USB install

Tags: ubuntu, usb-device

I am having some issues installing a ubuntu on a USB.

Well installing it is the easy part, making the partitions and getting it to boot is ok (following this) https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2338836

The problem however is only one ever wants to boot. if the USB boots, the grub on the main system needs repairing, if the main system boots or is restored the USB grub needs repairing.

I honestly have no idea why im having so many issues with this. any help? THIS IS NOT ABOUT A LIVE USB

My goal is to have a usb with dev op tools on that I can plug into a system, it boots without interaction and configures the main system.

the usb is ubuntu 20 and the main system 18

Comment: Do you have an ESP on external drive? You need one. Then you can copy /EFI/Boot & /EFI/ubuntu from internal drive to external. All UEFI external drives boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi, but Ubuntu full install needs /EFI/ubuntu folders. Then you can reset /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg to boot your internal drive. Or reinstall grub when booted into internal drive. https://askubuntu.com/questions/792413/how-to-set-grub-from-second-linux-distribution-as-default-in-uefi-boot Any second drive: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153

Answer (score -1):

I have set up a few of these with Xubuntu. I go into the BIOS of the machine I am using before installation. Then I disable the internal drives. (You can also physically remove it if preferred.) Then I plug in my flash drive and live USB, and I install Xubuntu to the flash drive. The installation will not see any other system. So, it will put GRUB and the EFI partition all on the flash drive. Then you can boot it on any machine assuming the hardware works with Linux.

Comment: So the plan with this is that the USB OS will flash the internal SSD with a img file and configure the OS. would I not be in the same position after re imagining? it seems every time I image something it goes wrong and something losses its settings

This would be so much easier in UBOOT :<

Comment: tried this and as soon as i plugged back in the drive and tried to boot the system it wigged out

Comment: It should work fine to plug in the USB system and tap F12 (or the boot menu key) and choose the flash drive from the boot menu. I am not sure why it would cause an issue with the main system. This has not been my experience.

Comment: I would also like to recommend being more specific with your description of the issue. Saying "wigged out" does not specifically communicate the issue which is occurring. Best of luck.

Comment: @TheHidden this might be a question of dialect, but for what it's worth I also have no idea what "wigged out" means. Do you mean the machine switched off when you plugged in the USB? Or did the USB cause a black screen or something? Maybe the USB drive itself died? In any case "wig out" is a new one for me, so I have no clue what actually happened.

Comment: @terdon sorry, it just means "went wrong or, in context, strange buggy behaviour" - when used to describe a person, it would suggest they snapped and went a bit "weird"... British phrase, ever heard "keep your hair on?" its from that, I believe, where aristocrats would "lose their wigs"

Comment: Ha! So it is indeed. I hadn't thought to look up [the etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/wig#etymonline_v_50133) (but did look up the meaning and found what amounted to "freak out"). Thanks, @TheHidden!